# Recursive Search and replace with / and '

Tags: perl, shell, unix, replace, xargs

I have searched and not found a solution so sorry if this has been answered before, I'm not great at shell.

I'm trying to do a recursive search and replace in all files via SSH.

So far I've got this:

```
find . -type f | xargs -d "\n" perl -pi -e 's/$this->helper('catalog/product')->getPriceHtml/$this->getPriceHtml/g'
```

I'm trying to replace this:

```
$this->helper('catalog/product')->getPriceHtml
```

with this:

```
$this->getPriceHtml
```

But I think its not working because of the slashes and single quotes. I have tried escaping these with `\` but to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: What does ssh have to do with this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate delimiter for the `s` operator could be used to avoid *picket fences*. `$this` will be considered to be a variable unless the `$` is escaped. The parentheses have to be escaped as well. Else they form a capture group. Since it is a one-liner and quotes have been exhausted, single-quotes have been encoded using hexadecimal escapes. The following should work:

```
s{\$this->helper\(\x{27}catalog/product\x{27}\)->getPriceHtml}{\$this->getPriceHtml}g;
```

Or:

```
s{(?<=\$this)->helper\(\x{27}catalog/product\x{27}\)(?=->getPriceHtml)}{}g;
```